# Find directories bigger than X and move to new destination

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I want to move all folders (max-depth=1) which are bigger than 100MB into a new destination. This here is what I've got so far:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h --threshold=100MB | head -n-1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -p -0 -I {} mv {} ../new_location
```

Somehow my result isn't being moved to the new destination, I just see a long list of all the folders I want to move, instead of them being moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-0` option to `xargs` means that the input is coming in **null**-separated, not newline-separated.  In your `awk` script, set the output record separator `ORS` to a null character `\0`:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h --threshold=100MB | head -n-1 | awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\0"} {print $2}' | xargs -p -0 -I {} mv {} ../new_location
```